# Facing SQlite3 module not found - SAP CAP sample

Tags: sqlite, sap-cap

I am getting error when running CDS WATCH from SAP trail business app studio for one of the samples.

I tried `npm i sqlite3 -d` and different options, but none gave me a luck ...

Below is console stack error log.

any helps are appreciated

Thanks
Rajesh

Console stack error log:

- node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download \
- node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(403): https://mapbox-node-binary.s3.amazonaws.com/sqlite3/v5.0.1/napi-v6-linux-x64.tar.gz \
- node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for sqlite3@5.0.1 and node@10.23.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
- make: Entering directory '/home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
- CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
- make: cc: Command not found
- make: *** [../node-addon-api/nothing.target.mk:99: Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o] Error 127
- make: Leaving directory '/home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
- gyp ERR! build error
- gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
- gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/opt/nodejs/node-v10.23.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:191:23)
- gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
- gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
- gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-4-cloud-amd64
- gyp ERR! command "/opt/nodejs/node-v10.23.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/nodejs/node-v10.23.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64" "--napi_version=7" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6"
- gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/sqlite3
- gyp ERR! node -v v10.23.0
- gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
- gyp ERR! not ok
- node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
- node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/opt/nodejs/node-v10.23.0-linux-x64/bin/node /opt/nodejs/node-v10.23.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
- node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess. (/home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
- node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
- node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
- node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
- node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-4-cloud-amd64
- node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/opt/nodejs/node-v10.23.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
- node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/sqlite3
- node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.23.0
- node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
- node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
- Failed to execute '/opt/nodejs/node-v10.23.0-linux-x64/bin/node /opt/nodejs/node-v10.23.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/home/user/projects/bookshop/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64 --napi_version=7 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
- npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
- npm ERR! errno 1
- npm ERR! sqlite3@5.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
- npm ERR! Exit status 1
- npm ERR!
- npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@5.0.1 install script.
- npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
- npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
- npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2021-01-15T19_20_11_562Z-debug.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following dependencies in package.json:

`"sqlite3": "^4.2.0"`

And run `npm install` in terminal.

This should install sqlite3. This can be verified in package-lock.json. sqlite3 would be updated there.